# Email forwarding go to IMAP account instead of POP3

Tags: email, imap, pop3, forwarding

I have same accounts (myname@domain.com) setup in Outlook with different account type (IMAP/POP3), most of the scenario all incoming email will received in POP3 account, my problem is, I got one email account (forward@domain.com) is set to forwarding to my inbox in Outlook if there is new incoming mail, but, whatever email as long it is included with `forward@domain.com` is always goes to IMAP instead of POP3 account, how can I set `forward@domain.com` to receiving in POP3 account as well?

thanks.

**Add on:**

In my outlook, my email account (myname@domain.com) has two account types which is POP3 and IMAP setup to get incoming email, both account type are configured as:

incoming mail server: mail.domain.com
outgoing mail server: smtp.domain.com

the only different between each is the account type: one is set to `POP3`, another one is `IMAP`

if the incoming message is sent to `myname@domain.com`, my message will be appear in POP3's inbox, if incoming message is sent to `myname@domain.com, forward@domain.com`, the message will allocated in IMAP's inbox. As long the new incoming message has included `forward@domain.com`, it will goes to IMAP's inbox instead of POP3.

I want all forwarding email will allocate in POP3 inbox.

Comment: I still couldn't follow you.. POP/IMAP is a form of protocol used in email communication and by your question seems bit unclear. can you cut it down and describe a little as to how each mails are configured which mails are actually configured to outlook & so... :)

Comment: @Azker Mohamed, please view add on part, hope you understand my question. thx.

Comment: Your setup is strange. Like Azker said POP3 and IMAP are protocols to access the same e-mail account. The difference is if you use IMAP you can manage you mails on the server. So if you create local folders or deleted local mails there will be also created a folder on the server or the mail will get deleted on the server. POP3 is the older protocol and more simple. It depends a bit on the configuration but usually pop3 just downloads the messages from the server and takes a local copy of the message. You can configure that the mails will be deletted after download or after a period of time.

Comment: you've said that mails sent to `myname@domain.com is appearing under pop3 inbox which is okay.. but I'm confused with this part `if incoming message is sent to myname@domain.com, forward@domain.com, the message will allocated in IMAP's inbox`.. from this, what I understood is that you have configured same mail account as POP and as well as IMAP is it?? Also check if there's any rule applied under your mail (IMAP account) as if a mail from `forward@domain.com` arrives then go to this/that folder??

Comment: @Azker Mohamed, yes correct, if a sender sent message to `forward@domain.com`, it will automatically redirect the message to `myname@domain.com`, this behavior is what I wanted, but I want it to appear the message in Outlook's POP3 inbox as well.

Comment: you didn't answer the last part.. have you set-up any kind of rules mentioning if to field says; `forward@domain.com` then send it to this folder or similar within your IMAP account???

Comment: @Azker Mohamed, you are right, after I recreated a folder under POP3 account, and assigned a rule to its folder, forwarding now go to POP3. many thanks.

Comment: you're very welcome. :)